# Hyperlink in JSP to add item to basket

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to add products (in `viewProduct.jsp`) to a basket (`basket.jsp`).
I'm pretty new to JSP. I know it's done by using an appropriate hyperlink to `basket.jsp` in `viewProduct.jsp`. I've written a long line in `<p>` tags in `viewProduct.jsp` where I'd like the hyperlink to be. Thanks

viewProduct.jsp

```
<%@ page import="shop.Product"%>

<jsp:useBean id='db'
             scope='session'
             class='shop.ShopDB' />

<html>
<head>
<title>My Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    String pid = request.getParameter("pid");
    Product product = db.getProduct(pid);
    // out.println("pid = " + pid);
    if (product == null) {
        // do something sensible!!!
        out.println( product );
    }
    else {
        %>
        <div align="center">
        <h2> <%= product.title %>  by <%= product.artist %> </h2>
        <img src="<%= product.fullimage %>" />
        <p> <%= product.description %> </p>
        <p> -------------------------- link goes here -------------------</p>
        </div>
        <%
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

basket.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Collection,
                 java.util.Iterator"%>

<jsp:useBean id='basket'
             scope='session'
             class='shop.Basket'
        />

<%
  String empty = request.getParameter("emptyBasket");
  if (empty!=null) {
    basket.clearBasket();
  }
  String item = request.getParameter("addItem");
  basket.addItem(item);
%>

<html>

<body>

<% Collection items = basket.getItems();
  for (Iterator i = items.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    out.println( "<p>" + i.next() + "</p>" );
  }

%>

<p> Order total = <%= basket.getTotalString() %>

    <%
    if ( basket.getTotal() > 0) {
        %>
<form action="order.jsp" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" size="20">
  <input type="submit" value="Place Order" />
</form>

<form action="basket.jsp" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="emptyBasket" value="yes">
  <input type="submit" value="Empty Basket" />
</form>
<%
  }
%>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JSP is for display only and should not have java code in it.  Separate it out so that you have servlet(s) for Control and JSP for display

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's not up to me. We were instructed to write in exactly this way so now i'm trying to make the best of a worst situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your `basket.jsp` if you have a parameter called `addItem`, then it will be added to the `basket`

so how about

```
<p> <%= product.description %> </p>
<!-- use pid -->
<a href="basket.jsp?additem="<%=pid%>><%= product.description %></a>
```

Although use of JSTL tags would be nicer.
See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't seem to be showing that it's added :/

Comment: Is the link OK though? Does basket.addItem get called?

Comment: It calls the method but it doesn't pass the value. I'm trying to pass product.PID to item in basket.jsp but when i print it after it calls that method, it prints null instead of printing the string which is what it should be printing

Comment: Updated my code to use `pid`  If you just use a browser can you add then item?

Comment: Just solved it but thanks for your help. I'll accept it as an answer even though i literally just fixed :p